# what does / slash mean in regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

what does the / (slash) mean before and after the underline(_ or any valid regular expression for that matter) . Is it same as ^ and $ cause I am used to writing in that way but have seen some guys write it in this way too. And also is it a particular requirement for the replace method in javascript or can I do without it?

```
var hello = "Hello_there."
    .replace(/_/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/_/g` builds a regular expression **literal**, just like `"_"` builds a string literal.

`/_/g` is the same as `new RegExp("_", "g")` but is compiled as soon as parsed and evaluated so is more efficient if you often execute this line of code.

When the code is evaluated first time, the big string that is the code is replaced by a logical structure where you have operators, strings, numbers, and so on. You have also regular expressions in this structure, which means the compilation of the regexp won't occur each time the code is executed but only once.

It's also more readable so should be preferred when the regular expression is constant.

The MDN has a [good documentation on building and using regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Thanks for answering dystroy but shouldn't the new RegExp("_", "g") be more efficient as I can store it in a variable and in that way I won't have to compile it again and again or am I not getting something ?

Comment: You can also store `/_/g` in a variable. There is no gain in using the constructor. `/_/g` is faster just like `"abc"` is faster than `"a"+"b"+"c"`. The documentation I link to also mentions that the literal is faster.

Comment: actually I didn't get the part regarding parsing and compilation...can u please explain it

Comment: I tried to be clearer but what you must get is that it's a literal just like `"abc"` or `123` are other types of literal.

Comment: thank you destroy I also happened to come across this article http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regular-expressions-in-javascript/    it seems to me that because regexp supports concatenation that's why it will be compiled again and again to check for any changes in the expression structure ....Am i correct on this ?

Comment: @Nav The constructor doesn't simply allow concatenation but let you pass any kind of dynamically provided string. That's it's *raison d'être* : Use `new RegExp` when the full pattern isn't contant.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes indicate the start and end of your regex pattern. This is just syntax.

Comment: so this is not same as ^ and $